# how to set position of value of JSpinner

Tags: java, swing

I ma using JSpinner in my java code, in JSpinner the the value of the JSpinner is appearing at the right side of the JSpinner but I want that the value of JSpinner should appears at the left side of JSpinner, so please tell how can I do that???

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Have you tried getting the JSpinner's editor via `getEditor()`, and then from that getting its textfield via `getTextField()`. You could probably set its orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried getting the JSpinner's editor via getEditor(), and then from that getting its textfield via getTextField(). You could probably set its orientation.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JSpinner.DefaultEditor;

public class OppositeSpinner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(50, 0, 100, 1));
      JFormattedTextField textField = ((DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
      textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you could change the Look and Feel's value for the `Spinner.editorAlignment` property via the `UIManager.put(...)` method. e.g.,

```
UIManager.put("Spinner.editorAlignment", JTextField.LEFT);
```

For a more complete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  UIManager.put("Spinner.editorAlignment", JTextField.LEFT);
  JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(50, 0, 100, 1));
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner);
}
```